# How do I combine these three JSON files into a single one with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have three JSON files containing category data. I want to combine all three to form a single one with a clear structure.

[**This**](https://gist.github.com/narzero/026f74e6e3d3121d6bd0) is what the first JSON file looks like:

```
{  
   "filterElementCommands":[  
      {  
         "property":"productTaxonomyLevel1.id",
         "value":"6401",
         "title":"Aardappel, groente, fruit",
         "numberOfItems":761,
         "numberOfSubFilters":7,
         "images":[  
            {  
               "width":198,
               "height":198,
               "url":"#"
            }
         ],
         "showGrid":true,
         "frozen":false,
         "links":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "property":"productTaxonomyLevel1.id",
         "value":"1301",
         "title":"Verse kant-en-klaar maaltijden, salades",
         "numberOfItems":382,
         "numberOfSubFilters":17,
         "images":[  
            {  
               "width":198,
               "height":198,
               "url":"#"
            }
         ],
         "showGrid":true,
         "frozen":false,
         "links":[  

         ]
      }, {...}
```

[**This**](https://gist.github.com/narzero/d7ce538662fea440228d) is what the second one looks like:

```
[  
   {  
      "filterElementCommands":[  
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel2.id",
            "value":"1789",
            "title":"Aardappelen",
            "numberOfItems":87,
            "numberOfSubFilters":8,
            "images":[  
               {  
                  "width":200,
                  "height":200,
                  "url":"#"
               }
            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
            "links":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel2.id",
            "value":"1628",
            "title":"Kruiden, uien, knoflook",
            "numberOfItems":39,
            "numberOfSubFilters":8,
            "images":[  
               {  
                  "width":200,
                  "height":200,
                  "url":"#"
               }
            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
            "links":[  

            ]
         }, {...}
```

And [**this**](https://gist.github.com/narzero/86645e296ba6dc00ae23) is the third one:

```
[  
   {  
      "filterElementCommands":[  
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel3.id",
            "value":"2341",
            "title":"Hele aardappel",
            "numberOfItems":37,
            "numberOfSubFilters":0,
            "images":[  

            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
            "links":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel3.id",
            "value":"5243",
            "title":"Krieltjes",
            "numberOfItems":17,
            "numberOfSubFilters":0,
            "images":[  

            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
            "links":[  

            ]
         }, {...}
```

I would like to combine them into a single one with the following format:

```
    {
      'property' => 'productTaxonomyLevel1.id',
      'value' => '6401',
      'title' => 'Aardappel, groente, fruit',
      'numberOfItems' => 761,
      'numberOfSubFilters' => 7,
      'images' => 'http://.../Aardappelen-groente-fruit.png',
      'children' => [
        {
          'property' => 'productTaxonomyLevel2.id',
          'value' => '1789',
          'title' => 'Aardappelen',
          'numberOfItems' => 87,
          'numberOfSubFilters' => 8,
          'images' => 'http://.../Aaardappelen.jpg',
          'children' => [
            {
              'property' => 'productTaxonomyLevel3.id',
              'value' => '2341',
              'title' => 'Hele aardappel',
              'numberOfItems' => 37,
              'numberOfSubFilters' => 0,
              'images' => []
            },
            {...}
          ]
        },
        {...}
      ]
    },
    {
      'property' => 'productTaxonomyLevel1.id',
      'value' => '1301',
      'title' => 'Verse kant-en-klaar maaltijden, salades',
      'numberOfItems' => 382,
      'numberOfSubFilters' => 17,
      'images' => 'http://.../Shelf-_0001_Kant-en-klaar.png',
      'children' => [
        {
          'property' => 'productTaxonomyLevel2.id',
          'value' => '1590',
          'title' => 'Stoommaaltijden',
          'numberOfItems' => 15,
          'numberOfSubFilters' => 0,
          'images' => 'http://.../stoommaaltijden.jpg',
          'children' => []
        }
      ]
    },
    {...}
```

Something must be going wrong with the loop, because I keep getting the same second level categories for all the first level ones.

This is the code I'm using:

```
require 'json'

def combine_all_categories(level = 1, args = {:invoker => :category})
  @master_array = []

  first_from_zero = JSON.parse(IO.read('/../first_from_zero.json').scrub)
  second_from_first = JSON.parse(IO.read('/../second_from_first.json').scrub)
  third_from_second = JSON.parse(IO.read('/../third_from_second.json').scrub)

  first_from_zero['filterElementCommands'].each do |one|
    @category = {}

    @category['property'] = one['property']
    @category['value'] = one['value']
    @category['title'] = one['title']
    @category['numberOfItems'] = one['numberOfItems']
    @category['numberOfSubFilters'] = one['numberOfSubFilters']
    @category['images'] = one['images']
    @category['children'] = []

    second_from_first.each_with_index do |two|

      two['filterElementCommands'].each_with_index do |three|
        @category_2 = {}

        @category_2['property'] = three['property']
        @category_2['value'] = three['value']
        @category_2['title'] = three['title']
        @category_2['numberOfItems'] = three['numberOfItems']
        @category_2['numberOfSubFilters'] = three['numberOfSubFilters']
        @category_2['images'] = three['images']
        @category_2['children'] = []

        @category['children'] << @category_2

      end
    end

    @master_array << @category
  end

  File.open("/../combine.json", 'w') do |f|
    f.write(@master_array.to_json)
  end
end
```

And **[this](https://gist.github.com/narzero/66c14994405048a2fbdf)** is what I end up with. The goal is to get all three levels, but I can't even get the first two.

What's causing this?

### **Update**

Thanks to Jay I got the first and second level working, but I'm having trouble with the third level. Some second level categories don't have third level ones. But they do get added from another category which breaks the entire category structure. I've updated the question with the code I've used. What seems to be the problem?

Below is the code I've used and it returns **[this](https://gist.github.com/narzero/e3173241c01774c4480a)**.

```
require 'json'

def combine_all_categories(level = 1, args = {:invoker => :category})
  master_array = []

  first_from_zero = JSON.parse(IO.read('../first_from_zero.json').scrub)
  second_from_first = JSON.parse(IO.read('../second_from_first.json').scrub)
  third_from_second = JSON.parse(IO.read('../third_from_second.json').scrub)

  first_from_zero['filterElementCommands'].each_with_index do |one, one_index|
    category = {}

    category['property'] = one['property']
    category['value'] = one['value']
    category['title'] = one['title']
    category['numberOfItems'] = one['numberOfItems']
    category['numberOfSubFilters'] = one['numberOfSubFilters']
    category['images'] = one['images']
    category['children'] = []

    second_from_first[one_index]['filterElementCommands'].each_with_index do |two, two_index|
      category_2 = {}

      category_2['property'] = two['property']
      category_2['value'] = two['value']
      category_2['title'] = two['title']
      category_2['numberOfItems'] = two['numberOfItems']
      category_2['numberOfSubFilters'] = two['numberOfSubFilters']
      category_2['images'] = two['images']
      category_2['children'] = []

      third_from_second[two_index]['filterElementCommands'].each do |three|
        category_3 = {}

        category_3['property'] = three['property']
        category_3['value'] = three['value']
        category_3['title'] = three['title']
        category_3['numberOfItems'] = three['numberOfItems']
        category_3['numberOfSubFilters'] = three['numberOfSubFilters']
        category_3['images'] = three['images']

        category_2['children'] << category_3
      end

      category['children'] << category_2
    end

    master_array << category
  end

  File.open("../combine.json", 'w') do |f|
    f.write(master_array.to_json)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand how you want these files merged, I think there are a couple of problems.

1. You need to keep track of the first index to get the second item associated with the first item.
2. Too many loops on the second level.

My code:

```
require 'json'

def combine_all_categories(level = 1, args = {:invoker => :@category})
  @master_array = []

  first_from_zero = JSON.parse(IO.read('first_from_zero.json').scrub)
  second_from_first = JSON.parse(IO.read('second_from_first.json').scrub)
  third_from_second = JSON.parse(IO.read('third_from_second.json').scrub)

  third_index = 0
  first_from_zero['filterElementCommands'].each_with_index do |one, one_index|
    @category = {}

    @category['property'] = one['property']
    @category['value'] = one['value']
    @category['title'] = one['title']
    @category['numberOfItems'] = one['numberOfItems']
    @category['numberOfSubFilters'] = one['numberOfSubFilters']
    @category['images'] = one['images']
    @category['children'] = []

    second_from_first[one_index]['filterElementCommands'].each do |two|
      @category_2 = {}

      @category_2['property'] = two['property']
      @category_2['value'] = two['value']
      @category_2['title'] = two['title']
      @category_2['numberOfItems'] = two['numberOfItems']
      @category_2['numberOfSubFilters'] = two['numberOfSubFilters']
      @category_2['images'] = two['images']
      @category_2['children'] = []

      # Use third_index to retrieve the item from the third file.
      third_from_second[third_index]['filterElementCommands'].each do |third|
        # Build children....
      end
      third_index += 1

      @category['children'] << @category_2
    end

    @master_array << @category
  end

  File.open("combine.json", 'w') do |f|
    f.write(@master_array.to_json)
  end
end
```

Abbreviated output, just showing titles:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Aardappel, groente, fruit",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Aardappelen"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Verse kant-en-klaar maaltijden, salades",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Stoommaaltijden"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

As a side note, in the code you posted, you can just use variables, they don't need to be instance variables. E.g., `category` rather than `@category`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the third level. Some second level categories don't have third level ones. But they do get added from another category which breaks the entire category structure. I've updated the question with the code I've used. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I was wrong about needed `two_index` for the third level. Looking the data for third_from_second, you just need to keep track of what index you're on for that file.

Comment: Edited code to show approximately what the third level code would look like.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
files = [
  File.open('json1.txt'),
  File.open('json2.txt'),
  File.open('json3.txt'),
]

File.open('combined_json.txt', 'w') do |f|
  while (len = files.length) > 0
    index = rand(len)
    if line = files[index].gets
      f.puts line
    else
      files.delete_at(index)
    end
  end
end

files.each do |f|
  f.close
end


--output:--

[  
   {  
{  
      "filterElementCommands":[  
         {  
   "filterElementCommands":[  
      {  
         "property":"productTaxonomyLevel1.id",
         "value":"6401",
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel3.id",
            "value":"2341",
         "title":"Aardappel, groente, fruit",
[  
         "numberOfItems":761,
   {  
         "numberOfSubFilters":7,
         "images":[  
      "filterElementCommands":[  
            {  
            "title":"Hele aardappel",
               "width":198,
               "height":198,
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel2.id",
            "value":"1789",
            "title":"Aardappelen",
               "url":"#"
            }
            "numberOfItems":37,
            "numberOfSubFilters":0,
            "numberOfItems":87,
            "numberOfSubFilters":8,
            "images":[  
            "images":[  
         ],
         "showGrid":true,
               {  
                  "width":200,

                  "height":200,
            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
                  "url":"#"
            "links":[  
         "frozen":false,
               }

            ]
         "links":[  
         },
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel3.id",
            ],
            "showGrid":false,

            "frozen":false,
         ]
            "value":"5243",
            "title":"Krieltjes",
      },
            "numberOfItems":17,
            "links":[  
      {  
            "numberOfSubFilters":0,
         "property":"productTaxonomyLevel1.id",
         "value":"1301",
            "images":[  
         "title":"Verse kant-en-klaar maaltijden, salades",

         "numberOfItems":382,
         "numberOfSubFilters":17,

         "images":[  
            ]
            ],
         },
         {  
            "property":"productTaxonomyLevel2.id",
            "showGrid":false,
            {  
            "value":"1628",
            "title":"Kruiden, uien, knoflook",
            "frozen":false,
               "width":198,
            "links":[  

               "height":198,
               "url":"#"
            "numberOfItems":39,
            }
         ],
            "numberOfSubFilters":8,
            ]
         "showGrid":true,
         "frozen":false,
         "links":[  

         }, {...}
         ]
      }, {...}
            "images":[  

               {  
                  "width":200,
                  "height":200,

                  "url":"#"
               }
            ],
            "showGrid":false,
            "frozen":false,
            "links":[  

            ]
         }, {...}
```